# How to create high res JPEG with Wand from binary string

Tags: python, imagemagick, wand

[image]

I'm trying to convert some PDFs to high res jpegs using imagemagick . I'm working on win 10, 64 with python 3.62 - 64 bit and wand 0.4.4. At the command line I have :

```
$ /e/ImageMagick-6.9.9-Q16-HDRI/convert.exe -density 400 myfile.pdf -scale 2000x1000 test3.jpg.
```

which is working well for me.

In python:

```
from wand.image import Image

file_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))+os.sep+"myfile.pdf"

with Image(filename=file_path, resolution=400) as image:
    image.save()
    image_jpeg = image.convert('jpeg')
```

Which is giving me low res JPEGs . How do I translate this into my wand code to do the same thing?

edit:

I realized that the problem is that the input pdf has to be read into the Image object as a binary string, so based on http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.4/guide/read.html#read-blob I tried:

```
with open(file_path,'rb') as f:
    image_binary = f.read()

f.close()

with Image(blob=image_binary,resolution=400) as img:
    img.transform('2000x1000', '100%')
    img.make_blob('jpeg')
    img.save(filename='out.jpg')
```

This reads the file in ok, but the output is split into 10 files. Why? I need to get this into 1 high res jpeg.

EDIT:

I need to send the jpeg to an OCR api, so I was wondering if I could write the output to a file like object. Looking at  https://www.imagemagick.org/api/magick-image.php#MagickWriteImageFile, I tried :

```
emptyFile =  Image(width=1500, height=2000)

with Image(filename=file_path, resolution=400) as image:

    library.MagickResetIterator(image.wand)
    # Call C-API Append method.
    resource_pointer = library.MagickAppendImages(image.wand,
                                                  True)

    library.MagickWriteImagesFile(resource_pointer,emptyFile)
```

This gives:

```
 File "E:/ENVS/r3/pdfminer.six/ocr_space.py", line 113, in <module>
test_file = ocr_stream(filename='test4.jpg')
 File "E:/ENVS/r3/pdfminer.six/ocr_space.py", line 96, in ocr_stream
library.MagickWriteImagesFile(resource_pointer,emptyFile)
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

How can I get this working?

Comment: What is the exact problem? What does the program output? What do you want it to output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why? I need to get this into 1 high res jpeg.

The PDF contains pages that ImageMagick considers individual images in a "stack". The [wand](/questions/tagged/wand) library provides a `wand.image.Image.sequance` to work with each page.

However, to append *all* images into a single JPEG. You can either iterate over each page & stitch them together, or call C-API's method `MagickAppendImages`.

```py
from wand.image import Image
from wand.api import library
import ctypes

# Map C-API not provided by wand library.
library.MagickAppendImages.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_int]
library.MagickAppendImages.restype = ctypes.c_void_p

with Image(filename="path_to_document.pdf", resolution=400) as image:
    # Do all your preprocessing first
    # Ether word directly on the wand instance, or iterate over each page.
    # ...
    # To write all "pages" into a single image.
    # Reset the stack iterator.
    library.MagickResetIterator(image.wand)                    
    # Call C-API Append method.
    resource_pointer = library.MagickAppendImages(image.wand,
                                                  True)        
    # Write C resource directly to disk.
    library.MagickWriteImages(resource_pointer,                
                              "output.jpeg".encode("ASCII"),
                              False)
```

**Update:**

> I need to send the jpeg to an OCR api ...

Assuming your using OpenCV's python API, you'll only need to iterate over each page, and pass the image-file data to the OCR via numpy buffers.

```py
from wand.image import Image
import numpy
import cv2

def ocr_process(file_data_buffer):
     """ Replace with whatever your OCR-API calls for """
     mat_instance = cv2.imdecode(file_data_buffer)
     # ... work ...

source_image="path_to_document.pdf"
with Image(filename=source_image, resolution=400) as img:
    for page in img.sequence:
        file_buffer = numpy.asarray(bytearray(page.make_blob("JPEG")),
                                    dtype=numpy.uint8)
        ocr_process(file_buffer)
```

> so I was wondering if I could write the output to a file like object

**Don't assume that python "image" objects (or underlining C structures) from different libraries are comparable with each other.**

Without knowing the OCR api, I can't help you past the [wand](/questions/tagged/wand) part, but I can suggest one of the following...

- Use temporary intermediate files. (slower I/O, but easier to learn/develop/debug)

  ```
  with Image(filename=INPUT_PATH) as img:
      # work
      img.save(filename=OUTPUT_PATH)
  # OCR work on OUTPUT_PATH
  ```
- Use file descriptors if the OCR API supports it. (Same as above)

  ```
  with open(INPUT_PATH, 'rb') as fd:
      with Image(file=fd) as img:
          # work
          # OCR work ???
  ```
- Use blobs. (faster I/O but need a *lot* more memory)

  ```
  buffer = None
  with Image(filename=INPUT_PATH) as img:
      # work
      buffer = img.make_blob(FORMAT)
  if buffer:
      # OCR work ???
  ```

**Even More Updates**

Wrapping all the comments together, a solution might be...

```py
from wand.image import Image
from wand.api import library
import ctypes
import requests

# Map C-API not provided by wand library.
library.MagickAppendImages.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_int]
library.MagickAppendImages.restype = ctypes.c_void_p

with Image(filename='path_to_document.pdf', resolution=400) as image:
    # ... Do pre-processing ...
    # Reset the stack iterator.
    library.MagickResetIterator(image.wand)
    # Call C-API Append method.
    resource_pointer = library.MagickAppendImages(image.wand, True)
    # Convert to JPEG.
    library.MagickSetImageFormat(resource_pointer, b'JPEG')
    # Create size sentinel.
    length = ctypes.c_size_t()
    # Write image blob to memory.
    image_data_pointer = library.MagickGetImagesBlob(resource_pointer,
                                                     ctypes.byref(length))
    # Ensure success
    if image_data_pointer and length.value:
        # Create buffer from memory address
        payload = ctypes.string_at(image_data_pointer, length.value)
        # Define local filename.
        payload_filename = 'my_hires_image.jpg'
        # Post payload as multipart encoded image file with filename.
        requests.post(THE_URL, files={'file': (payload_filename, payload)})
```

Comment: Thanks, So just for my own understanding: I'm assuming that the imageMagick program itself is written in C . and wand accesses the C API to provide some but not all of the functions?

Comment: Correct. ImageMagick is written in C, and ships with a C-API library called `MagickWand`. The python package `wand` integrates with `MagickWand` through `ctypes` module.

Comment: Ok Thanks, that does work. Can I ask for 1 more thing. Please see edit above.

Comment: Thanks, in my case I'm using an online ocr api (https://ocr.space/ocrapi), which is working well for me. I've tested it with the jpegs produced by ImageMagick. Using the 3 methods above I can see how to write it to disk. What I'm trying to figure out now is  how to pipe the output from : library.MagickWriteImages(resource_pointer,"output.jpeg".encode("ASCII"), False) to your code in 'Use blobs', and cut out the middle man (of writing to disk) if that's possible.

Comment: Ah! Just use `requests` package & `Image.make_blob`. Something like ... `requests.post(url, files={'file':('filename.jpg', img.make_blob('JPEG'))})`

Comment: Thank you, there is example code with requests at https://github.com/Zaargh/ocr.space_code_example/blob/master/ocrspace_example.py ,  but unless I'm missing something obvious I still don't understand how to  pipe the output from : library.MagickWriteImages(resource_pointer,"output.jpeg".enc‌​ode("ASCII"), False) to an Image() instance, without writing to disk.

Comment: Thank you, I could not have figured that out.

Answer (score 2):

What about something like:

```
ok = Image(filename=file_path, resolution=400)
with ok.transform('2000x1000', '100%') as image:
   image.compression_quality = 100
   image.save()
```

or:

```
with ok.resize(2000, 1000)
```

related:

- https://github.com/dahlia/wand/blob/13c4f544bd271fe298ac8dde44fbf178b349361a/docs/guide/resizecrop.rst
- [Python 3 Wand How to make an unanimated gif from multiple PDF pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40566955/python-3-wand-how-to-make-an-unanimated-gif-from-multiple-pdf-pages#40574731)

Comment: I pasted your code in but I'm getting:     with ok.transform('2000x1000', '100%') as image:
AttributeError: '__enter__'

Comment: The issue appears to be that I have to read the image in as a binary string. Please see edit.