# Unable to assign python wand Image object

Tags: python, imagemagick, wand

[image]

I'm trying to create high res jpegs from a pdf using wand. This question is a follow up to [How to create high res JPEG with Wand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47602208/how-to-create-high-res-jpeg-with-wand).

I'm getting the error:

```
with ok.transform('2000x1000', '100%') as image:
AttributeError: __enter__
```

Trying to step through the code:

```
Python 3.6.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul 20 2017, 12:30:02) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>>> im = ok.transform('2000x1000', '100%') 
>>> im
>>> im
```

you can see that I am unable to assign the transformed image to im. Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you can see that I am unable to assign the transformed image to im. Why ?

The method `wand.image.Image.transform` does not return an instance of `wand.image.Image`.

Also note. The MagickWand convenience method `MagickTransformImage` has been removed with IM-7. Use `wand.image.Image.crop` & `wand.image.Image.resize` directly.

```py
with Image(filename=file_path, resolution=400) as image:
    image.crop(width=2000, height=1000)
```